# Moq: Raises for method, returning Task

Tags: c#, moq

After changing return type of `Foo` from `void` to `Task`:

```
interface A {
  event EventHandler<EventArgs> Created;
  Task FooAsync();
}
```

test code not compiles (I want to raise event after `FooAsync` called):

```
aMock.Setup(x=>x.FooAsync()).Raises(x => x.Created+= null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        var task = Task.CompletedTask;
        var a = new Mock<A>();
        a.Setup(x => x.FooAsync()).Returns(task).Raises(x => x.Created += null, EventArgs.Empty);
        a.Object.Created += (s, e) =>
        {
        };

        await a.Object.FooAsync();
    }
```